# gitlab api: get all the project of a groups (with sub groups)

Tags: rest, api, gitlab

I want to use gitlab apis to get all the projects and sub-projects of the group, that is the info I get when I go to the group's page

I noticed that gitlab's ui uses

```
https://gitlab.com/groups/<group_name>/<subgroup_name>/-/children.json
```

To get the projects and subgroups of a group.

I wonder if there's something like that or I have to build it using the `groups/xxx/subgroups` and `grops/xxx/projects` endpoints recursively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [API endpoint to list a group's projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects) has an `include_subgroups` attribute that will include all of the projects listed under the subgroups, is that what you're trying to do?